# RHEL7 Strange Resource Starvation, repeatable 141 second stalling

Tags: linux, freeze, rhel-7

We have one RHEL7 system of three supposedly identical systems which regularly (every 5 days to a week) gets into some weird resource starvation scenario. The main symptom seems to be a severe delay in launching new processes (and threads?). I've tried and looked into a large number of things, in short the system looks entirely idle and memory and CPU are all readily available/idle...and while many processes may show up in a "D" state, /proc/stat shows `procs_blocked 0`. There does not seem to be heavy IO load.

Here's one odd manifestation of the problem I'm focusing on... on the last two of these occasions I've run the following and gotten reliably the exact (within 0.01s) same result:

```
$ time sleep 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
real    2m21.006s                                                                                                                  
user    0m0.000s                                                                                                                  
sys     0m0.007s
```

That is, an oddly specific 141 second delay to run `sleep 0`. Perhaps notable, I also did this:

```
$ strace -c sleep 0                                                                                                                                                                                                              
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall                                                                         
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------                                                                 
59.00   0.001606         535         3           open                                                                             
19.32   0.000526         131         4           mprotect                                                                          
8.89    0.000242         242         1         1 access                                                                            
6.58    0.000179          59         3           fstat                                                                             
2.87    0.000078           9         8           mmap                                                                              
0.96    0.000026           5         5           close                                                                             
0.62    0.000017          17         1           munmap                                                                            
0.55    0.000015           3         4           brk                                                                               
0.40    0.000011          11         1           execve                                                                            
0.37    0.000010          10         1           nanosleep                                                                         
0.33    0.000009           9         1           read                                                                              
0.11    0.000003           3         1           arch_prctl                                                                      
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------                                                                
100.00    0.002722                    33         1 total
```

So...those two don't really agree, which is puzzling...I expected to see some syscall eating up all the time, but (like many metrics in this situation) everything looks hunky-dory.

Obviously there are a million variables (e.g. this is a VM, I've looked at CPU_READY, etc.), and I've tried to look into ones that made sense to me to investigate... but that repeatable, whole-second delay is sticking out at me.

Any idea what would cause a 141 second pause in launching such a basic process? And on top of that, not show up as such in a `strace`?

## UPDATE

Okay, two new pieces of information. We shut down that system and moved one of the virtual disks, with 15TB of *stuff* to the newest server so we can copy all of the stuff off--the old disk is EXT4 and the new disk is XFS, so we're mounting and copying rather than just remounting the VMDK permanently.

**NOW THE NEW SYSTEM IS DOING EXACTLY THE SAME THING.**

So, *likely* the disk we moved over is a factor. However the configs of these systems are supposed to be almost identical, so it could just be manifesting itself later. But, yeah, probably that disk is a factor.

Here's the other bit:

I tried interrupting the `time sleep 0` command--that is, typing it, hitting enter, and then immediately hitting ctrl+C. Guess what?...

```
[matthew.williamson@nwcal-cee-ti04 ~]$ time sleep 0                                                                                                                                           ^C                                                                                                                                                                                            real    0m47.003s                                                                                                                                                                             user    0m0.000s                                                                                                                                                                              sys     0m0.004s
```

47 seconds... reliably. And if you hadn't already guessed, 47*3 = 141 seconds. So time sleep 0 is doing **something** three times that takes 47 seconds to return. What might that be??? guess I'll look at the strace again.

Oh... that disk is not the root partition, BTW, so neither `time` nor `sleep` should touch it... so that's weird... if it is related, it must be gumming up something real good in the kernel.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm realizing this question may belong on ServerFault instead of SuperUser... anybody with 3000+ rep who agrees can feel free to move it.